# Pdf file is not displaying on frontend

Tags: python, html, django

I have uploaded the pdf file in django admin panel. However, when I try to open the pdf file in html file tag, it is not opening.

HTML code:

```
  <a href="{{ opinion.tests }}">Your tests</a>
</div>
```

views.py:
def report(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
try:
name = request.POST['name']
phone1 = request.POST['phone']
print("name:", name, "phone", type(phone1))

```
        analysis = Report.objects.filter(phone=phone1)[0]
        opinion = {'opinion': analysis}
        return render(request, "reports.html", opinion)
    except:
        return render(request,"not_found.html")
```

models.py:

```
class Report(models.Model):
current_date = str(datetime.date.today())

name= models.CharField(max_length=100)
email= models.EmailField(max_length=1000)
phone = models.IntegerField()
previous_history =models.TextField(max_length=5000)
current_diagnosis= models.TextField(max_length=5000)
doctor = models.CharField(max_length=100)
tests = models.FileField(upload_to='ptest/', default="")

def __str__(self):
    return self.name + " | " + "Doctor : "+ self.doctor
```

File is displaying in admin panel. It is also uploading in the backend. The html page also displays without any error. However, when I click to open to see the file , it gives an error.

I am uploading a pdf file and i am expecting the file to be displayed in html file in the frontend.

Comment: Please add "an error" to your question. Paste the exact traceback.

Comment: Not Found: /ptest/GTT.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Your FileField should give the pdf a 'url' attribute, and that's what you'll want to point the href to in your template:

```
<a href="{{ mymodel.myfilefield.url }}" target="_blank">
```

Answer (score 0):

correct html code:
reports

by mentioning "/media/" folder path, it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).